# Skype crashes randomly after/during calls

Tags: windows-7, windows, crash, skype

Skype crashes randomly after and during voice and video calls. This is a screen grab of the error.

> Access violation at address 6D496E6F. Read of address 6D496E6F.

[image: skype crash dialog]

I can still use Skype, but I can't use any extras and the random crashes during the calls are very unnerving.

Any permanent solutions for this error?

My operating system is Windows 7 and I'm using Skype 4.2

---

This is the latest error I received with a skype crash:

> Problem signature:   Problem Event
>   Name: APPCRASH   Application Name:
>   Skype.exe   Application Version:
>   4.2.0.158   Application Timestamp: 4bba718b   Fault Module Name: dxgi.dll
>   Fault Module Version: 6.1.7600.16385
>   Fault Module Timestamp: 4a5bda0c
>   Exception Code: c0000096   Exception
>   Offset: 00006e76   OS Version:
>   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1   Locale ID: 1033   Additional Information 1: ff58
>   Additional Information 2:
>   ff58cecc66713c52ab4dcfe223c95d4b
>   Additional Information 3: 2729
>   Additional Information 4:
>   2729596ace3018576d01c758a04ac576
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not
>   available, please read our privacy
>   statement offline:
>   C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

And a pop-up from skype with an error that says **"Privileged Error"**

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling Skype?

Comment: yes did that and updated to the latest version of skype too.

Comment: Do you have any Skype plugins installed? Do you have other applications that interact with Skype? The fact that you can't use any extras leads me to believe you might have a mis-behaving plugin.

Comment: I'll check that up and get back on this post

Comment: uninstalled extras and reinstalled skype but still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same random error in Windows 7 when a contact came online, i suspected this contact has a virus-ridden computer.

**So i did a full anti-virus scan, removed all threats, banned that contact and skype works ok again.**